# Function call under onKeyPress in reactjs isn't getting called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

In the below code when i enter a search string and press enter, `this` is becoming undefined and as a result the function is not getting called.Can anybody please help me understand why? I have tried almost everything but nothing seems to be working neither could i find any pointers to the problem i am facing.

```
    class HomepageBody extends Component{ 
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    value :'',
    error: null,
    isLoaded: false,
    array: [],
    mobile: ''
   }
this.readSearchString = this.readSearchString.bind(this);
this.doSomething = this.doSomething.bind(this);
}

 readSearchString(event){
if(event.target.value === ''){
  this.setState({
    error: null,
    array: ''
  });
}
else{
this.setState ({
  value : event.target.value
});
}
}

doSomething = () => {
 fetch(`http://localhost:8080/items?search=${this.state.value}&page=1`, 
 {
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  }
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(
    (result) => {
      if(result.length != 0){
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        array: result,
        error: null
      });
    }
    else{
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        error : "No matches found",
        array: ''
      })
    }
    },
    (error) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        error: "We are experiencing some temporary problem, please try again later"
      });
    }
  )
  }

 render () {
const {mobile} = this.props;
return(
<Container>
  <Header
    as='h1'
    content='Title'
    style={{
      fontSize: mobile ? '1.2em' : '3em',
      fontWeight: 'normal',
      marginBottom: 0,
      marginTop: mobile ? '5em' : '3em',
      display:'block'
    }}
  />
<Input  icon={<Icon name='search' inverted circular link />}
    placeholder='Search .....'
    style={{
    fontSize: mobile ? '1em' : '1em',
    fontWeight: 'normal',
    marginTop: mobile ? '1em' : '1em',
    width: mobile ? '280px' : '600px',
  }}
  onChange={ this.readSearchString }
  onKeyPress={(event) => {
    if(event.key === 'Enter'){
      this.doSomething()
    }
  }}
  focus
/>
  </Container>
)
}
}
   HomepageBody.propTypes = {
   mobile: PropTypes.bool,
}
```

Thanks,
Vikram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, thats what i had done. But it didn't work. However i figured out a solution. If i'm not using the semantic ui framework's component, then i can define the function inline for onKeyPress and it works without any problems, but when i use the semantic ui framework and use the `<Input>` component, i have to override the function call. So this is how i did it

```
    <Input>
      ..........
      .........
      onKeyPress = {this.onKeyPress}
      </Input>


    onKeyPress= (e) => {
    if(e.key === 'Enter')
    this.doSomething();
   }
```

So i presume its got to something to do with semantic ui and the way it handles events within the component.

Answer (score 0):

Set an attribute of `tabIndex="0"` and it will work.

> tabindex="0" allows elements besides links and form elements to
>   receive keyboard focus. It does not change the tab order, but places
>   the element in the logical navigation flow, as if it were a link on
>   the page.

Comment: Nope, doesn't help. `this` is still undefined. :(

Comment: did u put it iin the input